# Changing the index of a For loop in Python (outside if statement)

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop

I am trying to change the index of a for loop depending if a user wants to go to the previous image (index = index - 1) and if he wants to go the next image (index = index + 1) however, the index doesnt change in the outerloop (outside the if statements).

```
flag = False
while flag == False:
    for i in range(len(all_image)):

        image = all_image[i]
        print(i)
        userchoice = easygui.buttonbox(msg, image = image, choices=choices)

        if userchoice == 'Next':
            i = i+1

        elif userchoice == 'Previous':
            i = i-1

        elif userchoice == 'cancel':
            print('test')
            flag = True
            break
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can't do this with `for`-loop. It will always get next value from `range()`.

Comment: This is it: you simply can't do that with a `for` loop - you need a `while` loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why the for loop is there, I'd be tempted to structure it more like so:

```
flag = False
idx = 0 #idx is where we are in the image list, and it gets modified by use choices in the while loop.
while flag == False:
    image = all_image[idx]
    print(idx)
    userchoice = easygui.buttonbox(msg, image = image, choices=choices)

    if userchoice == 'Next':
        idx += 1
    elif userchoice == 'Previous':
        idx -= 1
    elif userchoice == 'cancel':
        print('test')
        flag = True
        break
```

Comment: Thanks! The solution works. Yea, looking at it now, im not sure why I included a For loop.